# How does requires transitive work in Java?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Can `com.demo.invoice` access `com.demo.product.service`?

```
module com.demo.product {
    exports com.demo.product.service to com.demo.order;
}
module com.demo.order {
    exports com.demo.order.orderservice;
    requires transitive com.demo.product;
}
module com.demo.invoice {
    requires com.demo.order;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does requires transitive work in Java?

If module `A` transitively requires module `B`, then any module which reads module `A` also reads module `B`. In other words, the following:

```java
module A {
  requires transitive B;
}

module B {}

module C {
  requires A;
}
```

Is as if module `C` defined a `requires` directive for both `A` and `B`. You use `requires transitive` when a module has types as part of its public API that come from another module.

---

> Can `com.demo.invoice` access `com.demo.product.service`?

No, the `com.demo.invoice` module cannot access types in the `com.demo.product.service` package, even though said module does in fact read the `com.demo.product` module. This is because:

> ```java
> exports com.demo.product.service to com.demo.order;
> ```

Is a **qualified** `exports` directive. Other than the `com.demo.product` module itself, only the `com.demo.order` module can access the types in the `com.demo.product.service` package. If you changed the directive to either:

```java
 // unqualified exports
exports com.demo.product.service;
```

Or:

```java
// include 'com.demo.invoice' in qualified exports
exports com.demo.product.service to com.demo.order, com.demo.invoice;
```

Then the answer to this question would change to "yes".